# What languages does Xcode 6 Support?

Tags: xcode, programming-languages

I love Xcode as an IDE. I would like to expand my programming knowledge to include multiple languages, and would like to know which languages are supported in Xcode 6. Obviously Swift, Objective-C, C and C++ can be ran in Xcode. But is there a list of all the languages that you can use with Xcode?

I've been researching like crazy and am very surprised to see that this question hasn't been asked a billion times yet. There are a lot of code specific, "Can I write Perl in Xcode" type of questions, but I have yet to find a list of all the languages I can write using Xcode as my IDE.

Comment: You are asking a question similar to "What kind of houses can I build with this hammer?"

Comment: Are you indirectly implying that Xcode supports all programming languages...? Because that is certainly not the case

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[According to the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Composition)

> Xcode supports C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Java, AppleScript,
>   Python, Ruby, Rez, and Swift source code with a variety of programming
>   models, including but not limited to Cocoa, Carbon, and Java. Third
>   parties have added support for GNU Pascal, Free Pascal,
>   Ada, C#, Perl, and D.